# Want to acess /var/cache/apt/archives manully in file folders

Tags: package-management

I want to copy some archives offline in  archives folder, so please help me. Currently I am using ubuntu 13.04

And also suggest me how can I directly install software in Ubuntu like in Windows - offline. I am a new user on Ubuntu.